# error: ‘is’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, iterator

I would like to read two files.My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  ifstream inFile1,inFile2;
  istream_iterator<double> start(is), end;
  vector<double> numbers1(start, end);
  vector<double> numbers2(start, end);

 inFile1.open("newvel.dat");
 inFile2.open("newres.dat");

  // print the numbers to stdout
  copy(numbers1.begin(), numbers1.end(), 
            ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " "));
  copy(numbers2.begin(), numbers2.end(), 
            ostream_iterator<double>(cout, " "));
  cout << endl;

}
```

I guess I do not understand how istream_iterator works.Or I can solve the problem to read files as vectors and print them may be in a different manner?

Comment: What is `is` in your expectation?

Comment: You do not have anything named `is` where you declare and define start.

Comment: It looks like you blindly copy/pasted some code from the internet without understanding what it is or does, randomly dumped it into your program, then acted surprised when it didn't work??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
ifstream inFile1("file1.txt"),inFile2("file2.txt");
istream_iterator<double> start(inFile1), end;
```

there is no`is` thing in your code, so you get your error

Comment: @ marcinj. Yes,now I understand I have made a mistake.